# My title is overwriting my image in window (Python)

Tags: python, codeskulptor

I was having trouble displaying my image and my Title.  I narrowed down my code and found out that the title was somehow overwriting my image. It appeared to be the *draw_handler* that was doing this.  Right now, the code will only display the title.  So, my question is how do you display *both* the title *Fire Emblem Summoning* and the *image*?

```
import simplegui
title = 'Fire Emblem Summoning'
def Title(canvas):
    canvas.draw_text(title, [40,50], 24, "Blue")


def draw_handler(canvas):
    canvas.draw_image(image, (1440 / 2, 1354 / 2), (1440, 1354), (500, 225), (200, 200))

image = simplegui.load_image('http://cdn.idigitaltimes.com/sites/idigitaltimes.com/files/2017/02/03/fire-emblem-heroes-five-star-characters-legends.jpg')
frame = simplegui.create_frame('Fire Emblem Summoning', 1000, 400)
frame.set_draw_handler(draw_handler)
frame.start()

frame.set_draw_handler(Title)

frame.start()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one frame can use in the same time. So put all your code in the same draw handler function:
http://www.codeskulptor.org/#user43_OTR2cL61rxlqoO6.py